# Calculationg execution time of different algorithms and one of them always comes back as zero

Tags: python, sorting, runtime

I'm working though my degree and working on different sorting algorithms. I am testing the run time of different sorting methods such as selection, quick, merge sort among other. I time each one with the code below and change the variable depending on the sort I'm using.

```
import time

random.seed(72)
rand_list = random.sample(range(1, 50000), 900)

def algorithm_that_is_being_tested(): ##atibt
    code

atibtS_rand = rand_list
t_atibtS0 = time.time()
algorithm_that_is_being_tested(atibtS_rand)
execution_t_atibtS = time.time()-t_atibtS0
```

Then the next would be as so:

```
def other_algorithm(): ##oa
    code

oaS_rand = rand_list
t_oaS0 = time.time()
other_algorithm_(oaS_rand)
execution_t_oaS = time.time()-t_oaS0
```

I am them printing all of them as so:

```
print("Selection sort takes: ", round(execution_t_SelS, 10), "seconds")
print("Insertion sort takes:  ", round(execution_t_IS, 10),  "seconds")
print("Shell sort takes: ", round(execution_t_SS, 10), "seconds")
print("Quick sort method 1 takes: ", round(execution_t_QS, 10), "seconds")
print("Quick sort method 2 takes: ", round(execution_t_QS2, 10), "seconds")
print("Quick Insertion Hybrid sort takes: ", round(execution_t_QIHS, 10), "seconds")
print("Merge sort takes: ", round(execution_t_MS, 10), "seconds")
print("Radix sort takes: ", round(execution_t_RS, 10), "seconds")
```

They all have very different run times but for some reason `Insertion Sort` is giving a run time of 0.0 which I know is incorrect.

I added an extra space in one of the prints on accident and then the `Insertion Sort' was showing the correct true calculation time but then a different one (sometimes two or three) would then display 0.0. Is there a reason that this may be occurring? Is there a different way to time these algorithms that could prevent this error?

[image: Sorting Algorithm run times with Insertion Sort show 0.0.]

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

- edit: Clarification and grammar

Comment: Your functions sort the list in-place and the list is reused? You need to generate a new unsorted list every time

Comment: Besides what @IainShelvington said (`IS_rand = rand_list` doesn't do what you think it does), evaluating performance is such a common task that there's a standard library module called `timeit` which streamlines the process.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thank you for your reply. My understanding would be that this would duplicate the seeded list so that I could test the same list. My background comes from R and this is a process that I sometimes use. Would you be able to elaborate what this is doing so I know not to make this mistake moving forward?

Comment: Assigning an object to a variable name just gives that object a new label. You create a random list, sort it, give it another label, sort it again, give it another label, and so on, ending up with one list which you can refer to by any of several names. Insertion sort is very fast on already-sorted data, and it's not the first algorithm you tested.